# Design of class for a GUI frame

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I have a class **MainFrame** (subclass of **wxFrame**)
Now this class does most of the work like
creating Menubar, toolbar, panel etc.

Now for each event in menu/ toolbar there is a associated function like OnSave, OnQuit, OnHelp etc.
Currently (initial stage) i have made all the OnXYZ members of **MainFrame**.
But such a design is making me uneasy. Soon there will be too many functions inside a class.

My Question : How should i split the above method in several classes / files?

Or more generally how should i design my **MainFrame**?

NOTE : I have checked few question regarding GUI desgin on SO, but they are all for Python, tkinter so i didn't understand them well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concern is readability.  However, if you split the 'natural' MyFrame class, with all the little methods that look after each user action, up into separate classes then you may perhaps gain readability for each part, but you will risk making things harder to comprehend, since you have a collection of small classes that have no real reason to exist.

The best help for readability is good documentation!

Note that the methods of a class can be implemented in different files - it does not need to be all one source file.  So if the file with all the method implementations and their documentation becomes so long that it loads slowly in your editor, then you can split up the source file without splitting up the class.

I wonder if you are using a poor, or non-existent IDE?  Without a good IDE you are condemned to be constantly scrolling through the source file - and that can get tedious if the files becomes long.

OK, now just how many methods are we talking about here?  Are there a hundred or more?  If so, then I would suggest that you should be looking at your GUI design.  Your users are going to be pretty confused if they are confronted with a hundred possible actions every time they open you application!  If you split your GUI into several screens, each with a well defined and logical purpose, you users will be much more comfortable and your classes will be smaller!

Comment: Reading and managing both are my concern. Also i want to design class hierarchy properly and avoid a bad design. As for IDE i am using MS Visual Studio Express 2010 on windows and Code::Blocks on Ubuntu, which are very good. May be i am worrying too much about design, because users are not going to be confused.

Answer (score 1):

it's up to you if should split in several classes. My advice would be creating new derived classes if the widget will have too much events/elements/sub-widgets.

For example, it's ok the set all properties of the menubar directly in the Frame class if the menu is really short, but if it's big, use classes derived from the wxclasses, instead of creating new `wxMenu(this);` on frame, use `BarraMenu::BarraMenu(Frame*framepairecebe) : wxMenuBar()` in a `menu.cpp` file and just call it in the frame file (`menubar = new BarraMenu(this);`)

Comment: great suggestion, i wanted something like menu.cpp for the rescue. But how can say exportAsImage method inside my BarraMenu (??) access wxBitmap of Frame's

Answer (score 1):

That is the usual, to have all event handlers in the window-class. C++ doesn't have any limit of the number of functions in a class, so you do not really have to worry about "too many functions inside a class". Well, with the exception that it might be hard to read.

You can create sub-classes of the toolbar, and handle all events for that specific toolbar in that class. And similar with other controls.

Another way might be to have all event-functions in the main window only contain one line, and that is calling a function in some other class to handle specific tasks. For the "File" menu there might be a `FileMenuHandlerClass`, and the main window event functions just acts a a proxy to that.

Comment: part of my worry is functions will be numerous and sometimes lengthy, leading to reading problem. Second suggestion seems good.